# Install Flux in AKS with kubernetes RBAC enabled cluster via Terraform

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, terraform, azure-aks

I created an AKS cluster with an authentication option (Azure AD authentication with Kubernetes cluster). Added a group with one service principal and my own account. Now I was able to authenticate with credentials.
And now I trying to install flux extension via Terraform.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "azapi" {
}

variable "cluster_id" {
  description = "The cluster name to be imported"
  type        = string
  default     = null
}

resource "azapi_resource" "flux_addon" {
  type      = "Microsoft.KubernetesConfiguration/extensions@2022-11-01"
  name      = "flux"
  parent_id = var.cluster_id
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      extensionType           = "microsoft.flux"
      autoUpgradeMinorVersion = true
    }
  })
}
```

And using env variables of the Service principal

```
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
ARM_TENANT_ID
ARM_CLIENT_ID
ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
```

I got the below error after I'm applying it by `terraform apply -var="cluster_id=<cluster_id>"`

```
"error": {
│     "code": "ExtensionOperationFailed",
│     "message": "The extension operation failed with the following error:  Request failed to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/**<subcription-id>**/resourceGroups/**<resource-group-nmae>**/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedclusters/sandbox_cluster_n/extensionaddons/flux?api-version=2021-03-01. Error code: Unauthorized. Reason: Unauthorized.{\"error\":{\"code\":\"InvalidAuthenticationToken\",\"message\":\"The received access token is not valid: at least one of the claims 'puid' or 'altsecid' or 'oid' should be present. If you are accessing as application please make sure service principal is properly created in the tenant.\"}}.",
│     "additionalInfo": []
│   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this, it appears that the authentication token in use lacks the necessary permissions to carry out the requested operation.

Check that the service principal has the necessary permissions. You need to enable the `cluster admin` role as well as the `contributor` role of the cluster to read and write the cluster operations as shown.

[image]

While creating the service principal, create a Kubernetes service principal using Az CLI and assign it the `ClusterAdmin` role using CLI itself.

```bash
az ad sp create-for-rbac
az role assignment create --assignee <service-principal-app-id> --scope <resource-group-id> --role "ClusterAdmin"
```

*After doing this, I tried the same code as you and was able to deploy an extension successfully.*

[image]

[image]

If still the issue persists with the terraform deployment, you can use the Az CLI to authenticate the cluster and install the extension.

```
helm repo add fluxcd https://charts.fluxcd.io
helm upgrade -i flux fluxcd/flux --namespace flux --set git.url=< repourl > --set git.secretName=xxx --set registry.disableScanning=true
```

Add the extension with the below command.

```
az extension add --name flux
```

Get credentials from aks:

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group < xxx > --name sampleaks1
```

Create a secret and apply the configuration `.yaml` with the below commands as per your requirement .

```
kubectl apply 
kubectl create secret
```

[image]